# How to read text files in java and access those value

Tags: java

I am new to this technology. I have a text file called condition.txt which looks like this

> server_state running
>
> health_state ok
>
> heappercent 20%
>
> hoggingthreadcount 10
>
> stuckthreadcount 1

I have a java file, here I want to read those data from the file and want to access those values. like in my java file I have a  String variable called server_state. I want to put the value "running" in my String variable. How?

Comment: Please post your code/thoughts.

Comment: Look for FileReader and BufferedReader.. or Scanner..

Comment: Why dont you search on google about the same topic???

Comment: Please before asking such questions, google "How read file from Java". First answer is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to read from a file? The [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class is very good for that.

You will have to format your text document in a different way, which means if you are programmatically writing the file, you need to split the 2 variables somehow. In my opinion, a comma (,) or a colon (:) are the easiest things to choose.

- server_state:running
- health_state:ok
- heappercent:0.2 // Percentages will use floats/decimals
- hoggingthreadcount:10
- stuckthreadcount:1

  ```
  public void getProps() {
    String[] cur = new String[2];
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("C:\Path/To/Your/File.txt");
    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
      cur = scanner.nextLine().split(":"); // a colon is simpler.
      if(cur[0].equalsIgnoreCase("server_state")) {
        server_state = cur[1];
      }
      if(cur[0].equalsIgnoreCase("health_state")) {
        health_state = cur[1];
      }
      if(cur[0].equalsIgnoreCase("heappercent")) {
        heappercent = Double.parseDouble(cur[1]);
      }
      if(cur[0].equalsIgnoreCase("hoggingthreadcount")) {
        hoggingthreadcount = Integer.parseInt(cur[1]);
      }
      if(cur[0].equalsIgnoreCase("stuckthreadcount")) {
        stuckthreadcount = Integer.parseInt(cur[1]);
      }
    }
    scanner.close();
  }
  ```

I hope this solves your problem!

Jarod.

Comment: There is a problem . When I tried to print server_state it gives Null.

Comment: Update your question with code and output, and I will update my answer with with a fix.

Comment: yaa, your code is perfectly ok . actually its my fault to make my file in diff fashion. sorry bro .

Comment: Nah it's all good man. I'm glad I managed to help you out! :)

Answer (score 0):

i did something similar but to read sting and integer from CSV file, the concept exactly the same

```
public static Countries[] readObjects() throws IOException
{

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\countries.txt"));
    String line = "";

    Countries[] countriesArray = new Countries[32]; 

    int arrayIndex = 0;

    /***
     * Read File line by line and parse every line to Countries object and insert it into the array
     */
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
        /***
         * Create Country object from the line
         */
        Countries country = createCountryObect(line);

        countriesArray[arrayIndex] = country;

        arrayIndex++;
    }

    br.close();

    return countriesArray;
}

/***
 * Read string and parse it into an object
 * @param line from the file 
 * @return Countries Object
 */
public static Countries createCountryObect(String line)
{
    Countries country = new Countries();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line," ");

    while(st.hasMoreElements())
    {
        country.countryName = st.nextElement().toString();

        //convert country population from string to integer 
        country.countryPopulation = Integer.parseInt(st.nextElement().toString());
    }

    return country;
}
```

and the countries class

```
public class Countries {

    public String countryName;
    public int countryPopulation;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar program I needed to write for work:

```
public class LogReader {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    mapper("workId=\"1915900093138425722");
}


public static void mapper(String id) throws IOException
{   
    String sepText = "";
    FileWriter fileWriter;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Work.txt")));
    String line = "";
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
    {
        System.out.print(line);
       sepText += line.substring(0, 23) + "\n";

       int startAttIdMarker = line.indexOf(id);
       int midAttIdMarker = line.indexOf('"', startAttIdMarker + 1);
       int endAttIdMarker = line.indexOf('"', midAttIdMarker + 1 );
       sepText += "attributeSetId = " + line.substring(midAttIdMarker + 1 , endAttIdMarker) + "\n" + "\n";
       sepText += "********************************************" + "\n";
    }
    br.close();

    File newTextFile = new File("worker.txt");
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(newTextFile);
    fileWriter.write(sepText);
    fileWriter.close();
}
}
```

You feed a string to the function mapper and it searches for all lines with that string. It then writes those lines to a string which is in turn written to a file of it's own.

Best thing to do is play around with some sample code like this and see what happens.